# How do you implement size classes with a custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am making a custom keyboard for iOS. I am using a .xib file for the design, and I am using an IBAction to pull the title of each button on click in order to type. The keyboard is working correctly, and appears perfectly fine on an iPhone 5S and below (.xib dimensions are 320 width x 160 height). However, when viewing on any bigger screen, the keyboard does not appear correctly.

Am I supposed to set certain constraints? How do I use size classes in this scenario? Would it be better to programmatically add constraints or add them by hand?

Link to beta keyboard (not even close to complete) : https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7XwRCOfrcP2eFZ1dlJtX0V2THM&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

first you should select view of your custom keyboard

then select add constrain option

than select constrain like below images

[image]

give static height which you want,
 default keyboard size is 216

Comment: First of all, I can't select the view and set constraints. However, I did select all elements, and then applied the 4 constraints you mentioned onto every element. Now, however, the keyboard is completely blank. I will edit my answer with a link to my Xcode project. Could you please test it and figure out what I should do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply just Copy your keyboard.xib view and pest it on your view controller but you should set all button constrain , i put it on main storyboard see in below image & then you can add size class otherwise you should go programmatically   [image]

Comment: And how would I add constraints programmatically? Or, how do you implement a storyboard as a custom keyboard? Thank you!

Comment: How would I do this? (See above comment)